# Adding drop-down menu to chrome extension icon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know that I can associate a *popup.html* to clicks on the extension button. However, I want it to be a menu, like the one popping up after clicking on Chrome's own "Customize and control Google Chrome" button (located to the right of your extension icons). I tried to Google it but no one seemed to be talking about that. Am I missing any *common sense* about Chrome extension development?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

You can either register a click via `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` but show no UI, or open an HTML page in a popup. You can style it to look like a menu, but it will still not be like a native drop-down menu.

Note that you can right-click the extension button, <del>but the menu you get there is fixed. I submitted a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=56980) a long time ago regarding that, but it never took off.</del> There is a `contextMenus` context `"browser_action"` now that achieves this.

Comment: My old PE teacher used to say, can't means won't and won't means pushups.

Comment: so, what're the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

A practical example, since the documentation isn't actually that clarifying:

manifest.js

```
{
  "name": "Foo menu",
  "description": "Demonstrating context menus on browser actions",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Click me"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon.png",
  },
  "permissions": ["contextMenus"]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.contextMenus.removeAll();
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  id: "FOO_ACTION",
  title: "Foo",
  contexts: ["browser_action"],
});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  if (info.menuItemId === "FOO_ACTION") {
    // Execute foo using tab id
    foo(tab.id);
  }
});

const foo = (tabId) => { console.log(`Foo called on tab with id ${tabId}`) };
```