# Chrome Extension Download Context Menu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome extension and I want to add an option to the context menu that appears when you click the arrow beside a recent download.
[image]

Is this even possible? When I try to search this issue I can only find information on the right-click context menu.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As you've stated, I don't think it's possible in the recent download. Based from this [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus), you can specify  'all' which is equivalent to the combination of all other contexts except for 'launcher'. The 'launcher' context is only supported by apps and is used to add menu items to the context menu that appears when clicking on the app icon in the launcher/taskbar/dock/etc. Different platforms might put limitations on what is actually supported in a launcher context menu. You can also check this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295862/adding-drop-down-menu-to-chrome-extension-icon).